# Имя подсистемы из имени файла

Tags: oberon

Коллеги, есть ли где-то в BlackBox процедура, которая по локатору определяет, к какой подсистеме он относится? Или это нужно ручками прописывать?

Нужна

```
PROCEDURE P(loc: Files.Locator, OUT susbystem: ARRAY OF CHAR)
```

такая, чтобы

```
P(loc, ss)
```

при

```
loc(HostFiles.Locator).path = "Subsystem/Code/Module.ocf"
```

возвращала

```
ss = "Subsystem"
```

Answer (score 2):

В модуле `HostWindows` есть процедура `GenPathTitle`, которая может быть редуцирована до нужной вам функциональности. В целом во фреймворке Блэкбокс понятие локатора не привязано к понятию директории. Поэтому специальной общей процедуры для того, чтобы выяснить верхнюю директорию не может быть предусмотрено для локатора.

Comment: Я как раз и хочу HostWindows.GenPathTitle перенести из HostWindows в Windows, и следовательно избавиться от импорта HostFiles - а GenPathTitle ссылается на HostFiles.Locator. Потому что негоже из Windows импортировать HostFiles и вообще HostЧегоБыТоНиБыло.

И уточняю: мне нужна как раз не директория верхняя, а ответ на вопрос "к какой подсистеме относится локатор".

Comment: И кстати очень хорошо, что не привязано: можем, например, определенный вид локаторов предусмотреть для базы данных, и хранить все модули в ней. Или на фтп-сервере.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже действительно нет такой процедуры. Но я нашел

```
StdDialog.GetSubLoc (mod: ARRAY OF CHAR; cat: Files.Name; OUT loc: Files.Locator; OUT name: Files.Name)
```

и

```
Kernel.SplitName (name: ARRAY OF CHAR; VAR head, tail: ARRAY OF CHAR)
```

Поэтому, наверное, нужно самостоятельно реализовать нужную мне процедуру, и разместить ее следует в `StdDialog`.